# Shouldn't a legal entity such as the council, which is asking you to respond to one of their letters, include a pre-stamped envelope?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law

If I receive a letter from a legal entity such as the council, which is asking me to fill in a form and return it to them via post, shouldn't they include a pre-stamped envelop where I can send the letter back without having to pay for the postage myself?

My reasoning behind it is that I don't have a choice not to respond to this letter, because if I don't, I will be penalized. This means that I am forced to do something which will cost me money.

Comment: Honestly, you're really making a fuss over an envelope and a stamp? Regardless of the correct legal answer, this is a stupid question.

Comment: I'm just asking a question. I have received many letters with a pre-stamped envelope inside them because they were asking to fill a form and return it to them. I wanted to know more about it. You're the one who is making a fuss about a question which is posted on a website designed for asking questions.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't respond to the letter, you will be penalized. So why would they send you a pre-stamped envelope? Paying for communications is just part of your everyday life and shouldn't come out of tax payers' money.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that I am forced to do something which will cost me money.

The entity cannot know beforehand *who* will comply with such requests (or *how*, in situations where online compliance is an option).

The cost of a stamp & envelop is negligible compared to other more inconvenient, inefficient alternatives. For instance, the entity could require you to go to their office and provide information you could readily (or when it suits your schedule) submit via mail.

Filing a grievance to protest what you consider is an imposed cost would most likely be more expensive to everyone (including you) than the expense you would incur by gratuitously funding the stamp.